# Rotate text 90 degrees cross browser with Edge support

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I've got an interesting Edge-case (pun intended) with some text rotated at 90 degrees.

- The rotate transform works with Chrome and Firefox.
- The ms-writing-mode fixes a problem with Internet Explorer
- In Edge, the text is both written from top to bottom and then rotated 90 degrees = 180 degrees

How can I make the following work cross browser?

```
.rotated
{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    -ms-writing-mode: bt-rl;
}
```

Edit: Here's a screenshot and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5609osah/4/)
[image]

Comment: caniuse.com says Edge supports 2d transforms http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d have you tried adding a non-prefixed `transform` and/or a `-ms-transform` ? It is unclear what you are trying to do with `writing-mode` and exactly what isn't working. Maybe a screenshot of each browser would help.

Comment: What should the `writing-mode` do?

Comment: @feeela https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531187(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: No, not what it is intended for, but why do you use it at all? If I deactivate it (using Chromium) I can't see any difference.

Comment: @feeela It fixes the issue that IE8 doesn't support transform

Comment: Have you tried setting that property inside a conditional comment only targeting old IE's?

Comment: Found a solution. Since we no longer officially support IE8, we can ditch the `writing-mode` and add `-ms-transforn`. I've tested it with IE9-10-11-Edge. Example here - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5609osah/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Transform works great in Edge. Just don't use the `-webkit`, `-moz`, and `-o` vendor prefixes. Just use `transform`.

See fiddle [codefoster/9jbeqs2g](http://jsfiddle.net/codefoster/9jbeqs2g).

Notice that I set the `transform-origin` to `bottom left` so that it wouldn't get rotated off the screen and disappear.